# Compiler error with std::enable_if when substitution fails

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae

In the below code example, the second line

```
std::cout << "is_even (4.4) = " << std::boolalpha << is_even(4.4);
```

causes compiler failures because no proper substitution is found.
If there is an error, then how is this SFINAE? I thought std::enable_if is kind of SFINAE and the acronym means no failure if substitution can't be done. Where I am misinterpreting?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
bool is_even(T value)
{
    return ((value % 2) == 0);
}
    
int main()
{
    std::cout << "is_even (4) = " << std::boolalpha << is_even(4);
    std::cout << "is_even (4.4) = " << std::boolalpha << is_even(4.4);
}
```

Please don't say what i expect in this situation to happen. I am just trying to see how should i see SFINAE here?

Comment: The error is caused by the call expression `is_even(4.4)`. Since you have called a function `is_even` by passing a `double`, the definition of such a function must exist.

Comment: @AnoopRana : I know what line is causing the error and why. My question is how the term SFINAE is valid in this case.

Comment: Think for a moment what happens when you wrote `is_even(4.4)`. For this call expression `is_even(4.4)` to work the definition must still exist. The error is not caused by SFINAE as explained in my answer.

Comment: Sfinae is "**substitution failure** is not an error". All other errors are still there! Like a missing matching function definition. What were you expecting? That the compiler would just ignore the line?

Comment: @JHBonarius : is call to is_even(4.4) not a substitution with double? If yes, then what do you expect by SFINAE? In simple words, the code tries to substitute with double here and then fails. Where is SFINAE?

Comment: Sfinae is not some language grarantee that you don't get errors, it's a coding pattern. E.g read [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error). You're not following the whole pattern. Overload resolution means there has to be a matching function call. Exactly one to be precise, and that's where sfinae can be used. Zero matches is and always will be an error.

Comment: @JHBonarius : This answered me 
`struct Test {
  typedef int foo;
};

template <typename T>
void f(typename T::foo) {}  // Definition #1

template <typename T>
void f(T) {}  // Definition #2

int main() {
  f<Test>(10);  // Call #1.
  f<int>(10);   // Call #2. Without error (even though there is no int::foo)
                // thanks to SFINAE.
}`

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the call expression `is_even(4.4)`. Since you have called a function `is_even` by passing a `double`, the definition of such a function must exist.

If we call any function, then its definition must exist somewhere. In your case, there is no function named `is_even` that takes a `double` parameter and hence the error.

**SFINAE** still works here. For example, when the template argument is deduced to be a `double` and then `T` is substituted with `double` the condition inside `std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>` evaluates to `false`. Thus this function template is ignored and no error is produced at this point. That is, the error that you're getting is not due to SFINAE. **SFINAE doesn't mean that your program won't produce any error.**

Now, for the call expression `is_even(4.4)` to work the compiler can't find any `is_even` that takes a `double`. And so it produced error. You can confirm this by overloading this function template with an ordinary function as shown below:

```
template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
bool is_even(T value)
{
    return ((value % 2) == 0);
}
//compiler will find this definition now and no error will be produced
bool is_even(double d)
{
    return ((static_cast<int>(d) % 2) == 0);
}
```

Now for the call expression `is_even(4.4)` the compiler finds the overloaded `is_even` and hence produces no error.

**Summary**

The error that you're getting is not the result of SFINAE, instead it is due to the fact that the for the expression `is_even(4.4)` to work, we need the definition of a function that takes a `double`.

Comment: Do you mean call to is_even(4.4) is not a substitution with double?  In this case, T should be deduced to double isn't it? So where did SFINAE actually come into picture? I thought this is the place where T should have been deduced to double and i could see SFINAE meaning.

Comment: @Helena I explained the exact same thing in my answer. Look closely i wrote: *"when the template argument is deduced to be a `double` and then T is substituted with `double` the expression `std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>` evaluates to `false`. Thus this function template is ignored and no error is produced at this point. That is, the error that you're getting is not due to SFINAE. SFINAE doesn't mean that you're program won't produce any error. Now, for the call expression is_even(4.4) to work the compiler can't find any is_even that takes a double. And so it produced error."*

Comment: I think what you are trying to say is that SFINAE is just to block the creation of a particular template function instantiation i.e with specific types which are not allowed. In this case , it only allows to create instances with integral types. Correct?

Comment: @Helena Basically yes, the function template `is_even` will be instantiated only for integral types. So since `4.4` is not an integral type and there is no other definition for a function named `is_even` that takes `double`, you get the mentioned error.

Comment: I see. Just wondering why the name SFINAE. The code clearly says i want to have instantiation for integral types and thus it generates integral version of the function.  Under what situation it would have resulted in error if SFINAE wasn't there? I mean when would the substitution failure have happened as name SFINAE says don't treat substitution failure as error?

Comment: The name SFINAE simply means that the error is not due to substitution failure as demonstrated in my modified example.

Comment: @Helena I think your confusion arises as your example is too trivial, because discrepancy between `int` and `double` can be made with normal overloading resolution. For a proper use case of SFINAE,  just just think of overloading of multiple classes where the differences are much more subtle, like having a non trivial constructor, or being move only. Normal overload resulting could lead to ambiguous matches, thus you need a more fine gained control. Like I said in the comment above: you need exactly one matching definition, no more, no less

Comment: While your statement is true, I am not sure this is a great example, because when calling `is_even(4.4)` the compiler is not even gonna bother on checking if the first option is viable (there is a direct overload for that). I would replace the second with another `std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>` or something like that. That way the two alternatives have the same importance in terms of overload resolution, and the compiler will check which of them can be used (if both then it will fail with "is ambiguous").